# How to find direction of swipe in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am working on a swing application which run on a touch screen linux tablet. I want to implement a module in which i find that in which direction user swipe its finger on the screen. I am using MouseMotionListener to find the position of the mouse. But confusing now that how i can find the exact direction of the mouse movement. I only interested to find upward and downward movement on jframe. Can someone give me idea about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to add this example code illustrating @camickr's answer since it might help - as it got rejected as an edit, and I don't have enough points to add comments, here it is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class DragDirectionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drag Direction Demo");
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                    float lastY = 0;

                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Mouse released at " + e.getY());
                        if (e.getY() < lastY) {
                            System.out.println("Upward swipe");
                        } else if (e.getY() > lastY) {
                            System.out.println("Downward swipe");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No movement");
                        }
                        ;
                    }

                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Mouse clicked at " + e.getY());
                        lastY = e.getY();
                    }

                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is just a toy example illustrating the approach explained in @camickr's answer: tracking the y coordinate when the motion starts (the mouse button being depressed, in my example); then, comparing it to the y coordinate when the motion finishes (mouse button released, in my example - may need tweaking for touch, I don't know).

Observe the console output indicating what the motion has been picked up as. Good luck!

Comment: This is a perfect example.. i got an idea and will improve this according to my need. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user526206 Except the moment you add any controls to your frame which use there own `MouseListener`, your frame will no longer be notified of the mouse event ;). The answer is also just what camicr suggest in code form

Answer (score 1):

> I am using MouseMotionListener to find the position of the mouse.

I would guess you need to keep track of two MouseEvents:

1. the previous event (or maybe the mousePressed event which started the swipe?)
2. the current event.

so that you have access to the two points generated by each event.

Then you compare the two points using basic math. If the current y value is greater you are swiping down, otherwise up.